# Savings in bank of 62500

Tags: united-kingdom

I was saving up money to apply for my spouse visa to the UK. I had 80,000 USD which a few months ago amounted to 65000 GBP, now unfortunately I noticed that it's at 62,200, which is 300 pounds under the minimum.

Now I have savings of 1000 GBP in another bank account that have been there for over a year. Am I allowed to use more than one bank account or does it just have to be one? Thank you for your help.

All The Best,

Waleed

Comment: There's no requirement for it to be all in one bank account, but the money does have to be legitimate, and they will look into that.  If the fact that you have two bank accounts has a reasonable explanation, and the transactions on both accounts are legitimate, then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, money being shown for any visa application to the UK need not be in the same bank account. Both the accounts should be in the name of the principal applicant.